# Pulseaudio USB Microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a USB webcam with a built in microphone.  The microphone works and pulseaudio is able to detect it, but not listen to it, i.e. it acknowledges that it is there and lets me change the settings in PulseAudio Volume Control, but there is no bar indicating input sound levels.  However, when I issue `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start` and PulseAudio Volume Control reconnects, the bar appears.  PulseAudio is now able to listen to the microphone and applications such as Skype now work properly.  Restarting the computer then causes the microphone to not work again and PulseAudio must again be restarted.

My question is how can I get the microphone to work all the time without me having to restart PulseAudio?  I have already tried adding `autospawn = yes` to /etc/pulse/client.conf.